# A question on limit

Tags: limits

Suppose that $p_k>0, k=1,2,\dots, $ and 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{p_{n}}{p_1+p_2+\dots+p_n}=0,\quad \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=a.
$$

Show that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_1a_n+p_2a_{n-1}+\dots+p_na_1}{p_1+p_2+\dots+p_n}=a
$$

The hints are much appreciated. I don't want complete proof.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Limit to infinity?

Comment: Also the keyword [*Nörlund mean*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#N.C3.B6rlund_means) will be helpful.

Comment: @sos440: Thanks for the Norlund mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: at some $N$, $a_N$ is close enough to $a$ (how close is that?) and so is $a_n$ for $n>N$.  For such an $n$, we can say that the sum is at least equal to
$$
\frac{p_1a_N+p_2a_{N}+\dots+p_{n-N}a_N}{p_1+p_2+\dots+p_n}
+
\frac{p_{n-N+1}a_{N-1}+\dots+p_na_1}{p_1+p_2+\dots+p_n}
$$
How can we show that the term on the left tends to $a_N$ while the term on the right tends to $0$?

Comment: Could you kindly tell me why does the term on the right side tend to 0?

Comment: Note that the term on the right will always have $N-1$ terms in the numerator, and an increasing number of terms in the denominator.  Using the first fact, we can show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_1p_{n}+a_2p_{n-1}}{p_1+p_2+\dots+p_n}=0$$ (how?).  By that same logic, we can extend that for any finite number of terms in the numerator.